# Limit of the size of lists for customer parameters in crystal

Tags: crystal-reports

Customer list cannot be bigger than 1000 items in crystal report.

Any way of getting round this with changing registry setting below ?

To display more than the default 5 pages (or 1000 rows) add the following key to the registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 12.0\Crystal
>   Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV

Then add the following String Value:

```
MaxRowsetRecords
```

Set MaxRowsetRecords to the desired value. As far as I can tell there is not a value that can be used to allow an unlimited number but it will allow more than what I currently have a need for. Hopefully that helps others searching for this wonderfully undocumented feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This registry change setting works and is the solution for this .