# How to Expand Parameter LoV limit in Crystal Reports 8

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a **legacy** application using Crystal Reports 8 where I need to expand the length of the list of values shown in a Dynamic Parameter to beyond 40,000.  (Yes, I understand that is an insane number of values in a pick list.  This is a **legacy** app that I just want to keep alive a little longer, not fix the root cause).

I have found several articles (e.g. [Limit of the size of lists for customer parameters in crystal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17806995/limit-of-the-size-of-lists-for-customer-parameters-in-crystal) and http://www.forumtopics.com/busobj/viewtopic.php?t=159475&highlight=dynamic+parameter&sid=c777e51edb729afbc2054bae98a10e35) showing how to change the LoV limit (a.k.a. MaxRowsetRecords or MaxNBrowseValues) in the Windows Registry for newer versions of Crystal Reports, but have not been able to figure out the right registry key for Seagate Crystal Reports 8.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried this for ver. 8 so I probably will be not very helpful. But here are my 5 cents:

The registry key, which is valid for Crystal XI and above should be modified
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Business Objects\Suite 11.5\Crystal Reports\DatabaseOptions\LOV

My guess is that it should be something like 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Crystal Decisions\Crystal Reports 8.0.....

If you already changed this and you are using value 0 ( for unlimited) try to change the value to a big number ( for example 80000)